# ¿Como convertir a string la respuesta xml de un request en python?

Tags: python, odoo

Tengo en python un xml de respuesta de una api el cual no lo puedo convertir en string por tener errores de codificacion, necesito poder cambiarle la codificacion y obtenerlo en string

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RespuestaPreregistroEnvio xmlns="https://servicio.url.com">
            <FechaRespuesta>02-05-2021 23:19:07</FechaRespuesta>
            <Resultado>1</Resultado>
            <TotalBultos>1</TotalBultos>
            <BultoError>
                <NumBulto>1</NumBulto>
                <Error>266</Error>
                <DescError>El env\xedo no se ha registrado. CP del Destinatario no v\xe1lido, no debe superar los 5
                    d\xedgitos
                </DescError>
            </BultoError>
        </RespuestaPreregistroEnvio>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

y siempre obtengo el siguiente error:

`xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 373`

Comment: ¿En una variable de qué tipo lo tienes, si no es un string?

Comment: Eso esta en el response.content de la api, la api me responde con un xml pero delante tiene una b, indicandome como que es bytes, y como tiene problemas de codificacion por eso no lo puedo convertir a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si dices que los datos tienen por delante una `b''`, es porque ya los tienes en una cadena, pero es una con representación binaria.

Para convertir la cadena binaria a un string en otra codificación en memoria, utiliza la función `decode` de la cadena, a la que se indica la codificación que quieres utilizar. Por lo que puedo intuir, la cadena está en Win1252, por lo que lo puedes convertir con `cp1252`, por ejemplo:

```
binario = b'El env\xedo no se ha registrado'
str = binario.decode('cp1252')
print(str)
```

Lo que imprime:

```
El envío no se ha registrado
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, sinceramente me resolvio el problema, y me indico el camino para lo que tocaba mas delante, nuevamente gracias por la ayuda prestada.